# Display PDF with <iframe> vs <object>

Tags: html, pdf

From all I read here at SO about this subject, I still haven't got enough information on:

When displaying a PDF in a browser view:

1. Why isn't `<iframe>` recommended?
2. Between `<iframe>` and `<document>`, which one is more secure (I don't want my PDFs to run any scripts on them, as I understand is enabled by default in the PDF document)?
3. Should I even consider `<embed>`? Why?

I just want to display a PDF on the view and nothing else. Please help me understand the best route.

Comment: Typically, just a url directly to the pdf will do the trick. And is necessary for viewing on iOS devices. If all you want to show is the pdf, just use a url directly to it.

Comment: @Ted On which HTML tag?

Comment: the browser url... like [this](http://www.brainlens.org/content/newsletters/Spring%202013.pdf)

Comment: @Ted I actually want it to be displayed in the body of my website. Not as its own view.